# Using VBA to Add Rows based on a cell value onto another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a spreadsheet whereby I have a value in a cell in a worksheet called "Equipment" cell C5, for example a Value of 4.

[Starting Cell Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfQQW.png)

I need to use this value to copy a section of the same row (D5:M5) and paste it that many times into a worksheet called "Programming" also if this changes I would like it to delete or add where required, ignoring where there is a blank or 0 value in the "equipment" sheet

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y1pF.png)

I have around 30 different items and all will have different sections to copy but they will be of the same size. Also Could this look down a list of values all in the same column and do the same for all the values

I'm very new to VBA and have managed to hide and show tabs based on values but i'm struggling to get my head around this as it's a little too complicated at this point.

Thank You in advance

Lee

This is what I have so far, I have edited the code to what I believe is correct but it still isn't working

```
Sub copySheetCells()

'loop by each cell in column "C"
For i = 2 To Sheets("Equipment").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    'repeat copy x times (based on cell in column "C" value)
    For j = 0 To (Sheets("Equipment").Cells(i, "C").Value - 1)
        'define source range
        Source = "D" & (i) & ":M" & (i)
        'find last row on second sheet
        lastRowS2 = Sheets("Hardware_Programming").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'copy data
    Sheets("Equipment").Range(Source).copy Destination:=Sheets("Hardware_Programming").Range("A" & lastRowS2 + 1)
Next j
Next i
'copy headers
Sheets("Equipment").Range("D1:M1").copy Destination:=Sheets    ("Hardware_Programming").Range("A1:J1")
End Sub
```

I only get blank spaces, is anyone able to advise any further?

Comment: Code works fine, OP attached his xls file below and his "Eqipment" sheet column C was blank and that is the macro loop count hence he had no output.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, use this macro. Based on names `Programming` and `Equipment` as originally requested.

```
Sub copySheetCells()
'loop by each cell in column "C"
For i = 2 To Sheets("Programming").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    'repeat copy x times (based on cell in column "C" value)
    For j = 0 To (Sheets("Programming").Cells(i, "C").Value - 1)
        'define source range
        Source = "D" & (i) & ":M" & (i)
        'find last row on second sheet
        lastRowS2 = Sheets("Equipment").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'copy data
        Sheets("Programming").Range(Source).copy Destination:=Sheets("Equipment").Range("A" & lastRowS2 + 1)
    Next j
Next i
'copy headers
Sheets("Programming").Range("D1:M1").copy Destination:=Sheets("Equipment").Range("A1:J1")
End Sub
```

### EDIT

Please avoid copying the code from the answer and posting it back at your question, I replaced the `Sheet1` with `Programming` so you can rename that sheet in your workbook.

Macro seems to do what it does, the quantity in Sheet1/Programming was not provided (column "C" according to your initial requirements):

Source (with added quantity)
[image: Source]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hello Pav, Thank you for helping. I have tried your suggestion and although I believe I understand the code now I still can't get it to copy the parts of the rows I need. I have added a link below to the file. Are you able to take a look and see where I went wrong?    https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8KHS4e3ETm0VEhvTTFlT0c1U1E?usp=sharing      Thank You

Comment: @Lee King fundamental problem is that you spreadsheet doen't meet the starting cell image that you attached. Macro works perfectly fine.
It will run that many times as many records it will find in the Sheet1 column C. In the file that you have on gDrive that column is empty!
When I have put some numbers in then it works.

Comment: @LeeKing see revised answer above, populate your spreadsheet with desired quantity for each device on "Programming" and it will be working fine.

Comment: @Pav - I saw you have an edit pending approval on the question to rollback an earlier edit made by the OP. I'm not sure what you're trying to gain by rolling back the edit?

Comment: @TomRedfern have a look at what was the OP edit, he pasted in the code which was provided as my answer with a comment that its getting somewhere while it still doesn't work. In reality it was a fully functional solution that didn't work due to his spreadsheet not having the data that he presented in the graphics attached to his question. When I investigated the xlsm file that he linked it lacked the Column "C" data containing quantity which is the count of macro loops execution and a requirement of the amount of repetition that wants to see as a result.. No data resulted in lack of actions.

Comment: @Pav - while I understand that it can be frustrating when users behave in a certain manner, the solution to this is not to get into an edit war. Despite being irritating the OP is perfectly within their right to update their question as they acquire new learnings. You have done your job and posted a complete solution. If the OP doesn't accept that you have two choices, leave it alone or try to communicate further and make them understand (or both).

Comment: @TomRedfern I did the edit for another user not to investigate an issue that doesn't really exist as I pointed the problem in the comment to the OP and updated my answer. If the question was to be updated it should rather say that using an x user solution it got me somewhere but still doesn't work the way I wanted because...

Comment: @TomRedfern - so you say "solution to this is not to get into an edit war" and then you edit the post to remove my edit that you do not agree with...

Comment: @Pav - I've already said I understand and your frustration with the OP copying your complete, working solution and implementing it in a flawed manner without giving any kind of credit for your effort. However, this is what people do sometimes. Regardless, you cannot just go and edit someone else's question unless it's for clarity, grammar, etc. Your answer still stands as a complete solution and will help others with similar problems in the future. As an answer writer on SO, that is how it works - you post an answer and then move on. I'm sorry if you feel I'm acting against you.

Comment: @Pav - also, addressing your previous comment *I did the edit for another user not to investigate an issue that doesn't really exist* - another way to address this is to post a comment directly under the OPs post, pointing out why what they have done is wrong. This will call out to other users so they are not led astray.

Comment: @TomRedfern I don't feel that you are acting against me, you have a different opinion on that topic. I still think that as the OP was using correct solution based on different example than his current data set it should not form a part of his question. I will leave it as it is though and move on. No need for any of us to waste more time here, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem :)

```
    For i = 1 To 30 Step 1
            If Sheets("Equipment").Cells(1 + 4, 3).Value > 0 Then
            Sheet1.Range(Cells(i + 3, 5), Cells(i + 3, 13)).Copy
                For j = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(1 + 4, 3).Value Step 1
                LR = Sheets("Programming").Cells(Sheets("Programming").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Sheets("Programming").Range("A" & LR + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Next
            End If
Next
```

Cheers ;)